# highlight table row with jquery depends on hour value

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have **table** `<table class="model">` with **td** `class="model-date"`.

Date format:

```
DD-MM HH:MM
```

eg. `<td class="model_date">30-11 15:00</td>` Is this possible to highlight red table **row** contains current hour (eg. 15:33 row contains **td** `class="model_date">30-11 15:00</td>`) with jquery and css?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, it would be useful if you included what you have already tried to do and why it didn't work for you in order to help others help you. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Somehow like this:

```
$('td.model_date').css('background-color', 'red');
```

Comment: Thanks, but your answer set red background for all td.model_date (not a row- I have more td i one table row). I wish to find current time 
var now = new Date();
var hours = now.getHours();
and after that highlight whole row contains only td with hour  equal var hours

Answer (score 0):

I do it with this code

```
    <script>

        $(document).ready(function() {
    var now = new Date();
            var hours = now.getHours();
            var months = now.getMonth();
            var days = now.getDate();
            var cell = $('.model_date');

        cell.each(function() {  
        aDate = $(this).text();
        resulthours = parseInt(aDate.substring(6, 8));
        resultmonths = parseInt(aDate.substring(3, 5))-1;
        resultdays = parseInt(aDate.substring(1, 3));

        if (resulthours == hours && resultmonths == months && resuldtays == days) 
        {$(this).parent().css({'background-color' : '#DBDBDB'});}
        });
    });
</script>
```